# Error adding customers to subscription in stripe

Tags: javascript, php, html, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a customer and create a subscription.

- But when I do it I get error.
- I tried doing it the node.js way and the php way. via node.js
- I have installed stripe and via php I've installed composer and stripe/stripe-php.

When I do it the javascript way everything goes find and handy with no error out put but when I go to the stripe daashboard there is no new creation of a customer or subscription in the test mode data.

```
<?php // Create a customer using a Stripe token

// If you're using Composer, use Composer's autoload:
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

// Be sure to replace this with your actual test API key
// (switch to the live key later)
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("pk_test_pjUIBAynO2WA1gA7woSLBny3");

try
{
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
    'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
    'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
  ]);

  $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'items' => [['plan' => 'gold']],
  ]);

  if ($subscription->status != 'incomplete')
  {
    header('Location: thankyou.html');
  }
  else
  {
    header('Location: payment_failed.html');
    error_log("failed to collect initial payment for subscription");
  }
  exit;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  header('Location:oops.html');
  error_log("unable to sign up customer:" . $_POST['stripeEmail'].
    ", error:" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

and this is the html file

```
<form action="/create_subscription.php" id="start" method="POST">
                <script
                  src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                  data-key="pk_test_pjUIBAynO2WA1gA7woSLBny3"

                  data-name="500 a month package"
                  data-description="Subscription will be billed every 30 days"
                  data-amount="50000"
                  data-label="Get Started!">
                </script>
                <script>
                  var stripe = require("stripe")("pk_test_pjUIBAynO2WA1gA7woSLBny3");
                  var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;
                  stripe.subscriptions.create({
                  customer: id,
                  items: [
                    {
                       plan: "prod_EtGDP9qICl6tvW",
                       interval: "month"
                      },
                  ]

                      }  , function(err, subscription) {
                  // asynchronously called
                  function(err, custumor){
                  if(err){
                    res.send({
                      success: false,
                      message:'Error'
                    });
                  } else {
                    const { id } = customer;
                  }
           };
              stripe.customers.create({
                email:"jenny@rosen.com",
                source: stripeToken,
               },
                function(err, custumor){
                  if(err){
                    res.send({
                      success: false,
                      message:'Error'
                    });
                  } else {
                    const { id } = customer;
                  }
                });
                </script>
              </form>
```

Comment: Do you have a Node.js server running?  I'm confused.

Comment: If you're keeping the concrete error a secret, this question might well go unanswered. (Also stop decorating each question with "please help!!".)

Comment: I don't think any of this code will work — it all uses a public key(`pk_test`) with API calls that have to take place on a backend server and use a secret key(`sk_test`) instead. The "Node" code also looks like backend Node code for parsing a request and calling the Stripe API, put into a frontend `<script>` tag, so that won't work either.

Comment: for the js file the error is that it doesnt update subscriptions or my customers. yes i have a node.js running and am on a website with https

Comment: so how else will i call the backed node code? how to i make the form submit to a seperate js file. and i tried using secret key but it said tht is wasnt valid or something. i do i have to use public key and secret key?